# Notepad++ Regex Find/Replace Using Look Behind not Working

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++, lookbehind

I have the following CSS markup.

```
.previous-container{
    float:left;
}
.primary-commands {
    float:right;
}
```

Using the regex syntax search `(?<=[\s,;])([a-zA-Z\-]+):` it highlights the CSS property name as expected, however, upon clicking replace nothing is replaced. I have tried using group token syntax in replace line e.g. `$[nth group]` and any plain literal string replacement. No matter my attempts it will not replace the matched string with anything. I am using notepad++ version 6.7.5. Perhaps there is something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: If you don't want to get into madness (npp has sometimes totally crazy behaviors), use PHP with sabberworm: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser/tree/master/lib/Sabberworm/CSS

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug to me.  lookaheads and negative lookbehinds seem to work all right, I think, and your example seems to work if you hit "replace all", or if you cut the text in half such that only one match is found.

Comment: There is no problem with `(?<=[\s,;])([a-zA-Z\-]+):` using Perl regular expression in a replace in text editor UltraEdit v22.20. What about using in Notepad++ as search string `([\s,;])([a-zA-Z\-]+):` and begin replace string with `$1`, i.e. use a capturing group for character which must exist left of string to really find and back-reference this character in replace string at beginning to keep it unmodified on replace?

Comment: @Mofi, I like that as a work around. Since it is a set number of matched groups at the beginning (as opposed to variable number of matching groups) this should achieve what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @femtoRgon I didn't try the "replace all" button, good observation. That sounds like perhaps another work around to this issue. I was using single replace to monitor replacements to make sure it was working properly. This regex expression is only part of a larger one that I was attempting to use on a 1000+ lines CSS file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on comments to the original question here are some work-arounds that solved my problem.

Option #1

Replace the lookbehind portion of the regex statement `(?<=[\s,;])` with a simple non-lookbehind group matching statement such as `([\s,;])`. This will continue to limit search results to strings beginning with the specified characters in the lookbehind. The only caveat is that in my replacement string e.g. `$1 $2` I would need to leave out the undesired matched characters that should not be a part of the replacement string.

Option #2

Use the "Replace All" button. It will perform replacements correctly when using a positive lookbehind in your regex statement as opposed to using the "Replace" button for single replacement.

I went with Options #1 only because it achieves what I need while allowing me to still perform a single replacement at a time. With larger documents I don't want to use "Replace All" until I have thoroughly tested my regex expression.

Comment: I used Option #2 and it worked with the "Replace All" button, but I couldn't figure it out why the normal "Replace" button wasn't able to replace a group.