# Problem with regular expression using look behind feature

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I try to build simple regular expression to remove some parts of bad (unwanted) code and needed use look behind feature.

It worked until i added `\s+` to it to exclude spaces from mark.

Eliminating parts of expression i finally got to `(?<=\s+)foo` which is still warned as invalid expression.

It may looks a little weird or unclear so expanding it:
`(?<=foo\s+)bar` is warned as invalid expression, where `(?<=foo)\s+bar` is working but it marks spaces before bar.

I am use it in notepad++.

Comment: From Regex101 : "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width"

Comment: I think using a quantifier in the lookbehind is not supported. You might use `\bfoo\s+\Kbar` instead.

Comment: Variable length lookbehinds are only available in certain flavors of regex such as .net

Comment: I don't think you need a lookbehind. If you're trying to remove stuff, use capturing groups to mark what you want to keep, and leave the rest out. This will basically remove the rest.

Comment: You can use a word boundary to enforce the actual start of a word: `\bfoo` would make certain that foo is preceded by non-word chars.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Make your comment an answer. In fact, Notepad++ doesn't support variable length lookbehind.

Comment: Thank You, didn't know about such limitation of look behind. Yes, it can be solved in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment by [@Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto) Notepad++ does not support [variable length lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#width). It uses the [boost](https://www.boost.org/) regex.

Notepad++ does support `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

```
\bfoo\s+\Kbar\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3XByP9/1)

Another way is to capture bar in a capturing group.

```
\bfoo\s+(bar)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Wbs2A/1)

---

**Note** that `\s` also matches a newline, and perhaps you might also use `\h+` to match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters.

Comment: I wasn't able to construct it with \b \K - not worked somehow, so I just pulled out \s+ from look behind. But there is bigger issue now, because notepad++ stopped replacing anything which has look behind in search phrase with replace button. Replace all works, replace step by step not. Replace button works now like search next. Even my previous constructions are not working now. I have found something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095915/notepad-regex-find-replace-using-look-behind-not-working but there is no solution to it. I reopened notepad++ or file and no fixed.

Comment: If the words foo or bar are part of a larger word, you could omit the word boundaries `foo\s+\Kbar`